# Disable signalr console logging

Tags: javascript, logging, signalr

using signalR in Javascript client. (backend is asp.net core).

I want to disable the console logging for signalr. basically, to stop this:

[image]

I have done this (but makes no difference):

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("./NotificationUserHub").build();
connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000;
connection.logging = false;
```

someone please correct me?

thanks

Answer (score 16):

You just need to add this to your code `.configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.None)` like this:

```js
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.None).withUrl("./NotificationUserHub").build();
```

You can see more log levels in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@aspnet/signalr/loglevel?view=signalr-js-latest).

Comment: thank you. I have put this in but it made no difference :(

Comment: Very strange, you are exactly saying that you don't want to log at all... You get any log if you can connect to the service?

Answer (score 3):

May 2022 update:

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from "@microsoft/signalr";
```

```
const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl()
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.None)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to disable logging.

```
import { ILogger, LogLevel, HubConnectionBuilder } from "@aspnet/signalr";

export class MyLogger implements ILogger {
    log(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
        // Use `message` and `logLevel` to record the log message to your own system
    }
}

// later on, when configuring your connection...

let connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/my/hub/url")
    .configureLogging(new MyLogger())
    .build();
```

This might help someone.